# Increasing speed using multiprocessing module in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am testing out the multiprocessing module in Python using this example. It counts the length of each word in a corpus.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def open_file(file):
    with open(file) as f:
        f = f.read()
    return f

def split_words(file):
    f = open_file(file)
    return [[len(i), i] for i in f.split()]


def split_mult(file):
    #uses the multiprocessing module
    pool = Pool(processes = 4)  
    work = pool.apply_async(split_words, [file])
    return work.get()

print split_words("random.txt") - about 90seconds for a 110K file
print split_mult("random.txt") - about 90seconds for a 110K file
```

The *split_mult* function uses multiprocessing and *split_words* does not. I was under the impression that I would see faster processing time using the multiprocessing module but there is little to no difference in runtime. I've run each function about 5 times. Is there something I'm missing?

**UPDATE:**

I rewrote the code with a better understanding of multiprocessing and was able to get processing time down to ~ 12 seconds! It's quick and dirty code but hopefully helpful to others trying to understand this concept - https://github.com/surajkapoor/MultiProcessing-Test/blob/master/multi.py

Comment: Is that your whole code, I don't see anything which would benefit of multiprocessing here.

Comment: IPython has much more capabilities to do high level parallelization - checkout http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_intro.html

Comment: @dav1d yep, that's my entire code. I think I misunderstood the module's purpose :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python does not have the facilities to magically make your code work in parallel.

What you did here is made a pool of 4 processes, and gave it one task, which will be run in 1 process.

A process/thread pool is used to run a large number of tasks in parallel (at most 4, or whatever you specify, at a time).
Splitting a task into many subtasks is the programmer's responsibility.

Comment: You are right, I seem to have misunderstood the module's purpose. So, effectively, if I gave split_mult several text files to process it will do them concurrently and at a faster speed than giving them individually to the split_word function?

Comment: Splitting 4 strings in parallel works. Splitting one string in parallel (as in your code), won't. Python doesn't magically make non-parallel functions parallel (split in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I/O intensive tasks can be *slowed down* by making them more parallel. This is particularly the case with mechanical hard drives.

Imagine you were able to divide the file into 4 parts and run 4 processes they would be causing the drive to seek more than reading the file once sequentially.

The same situation occurs if you had 4 workers on 4 files, but you don't have to think about how to split the file.

If `len` were a time consuming operation, you may see a performance improvement by reading the file *sequentially* line by line and have the workers pull those lines from a `Queue`. However unless you have very fast storage (maybe the file is cached) it will not make much difference.